# how to get Display structure of an existing window using xlib

Tags: c, linux, xlib, x11

I know that XOpenDisplay(), crates a connection to the xserver and returns Display structure,
but is there any way to get the reference to the Display structure of the existing windows, So that I can get the window properties of all windows that are opened currently ?
I want to know the current focused window, but XGetInputFocus() is asking for Display ref. as an argument. How do i get this Dsiplay ref. ? Kindly help me as i'm a fresher to X11?

Correct me if i'm wrong any where..

Thank you!

Comment: This makes no sense. To obtain a window you must have a display in the first place.

Comment: @n.m. : except if a third-party library manages the windows for you - it really makes sense to be able to get a hand onto a Window* without knowing about the Display.

Comment: @Tibo A third party library that gives you windows but not Display? Do you have an example in mind?

Comment: @n.m. Using wxWidgets, for instance, you can get a handle to an existing window using wxWindow::GetHandle(). You might want to give this window to another library (e.g. VLC to stream video, OpenGL, etc.). You are even further away from the X11 details if you use wxPython (real life example).

Comment: For the record, knowing that my window was a GTK2 window, I used ``gdk_window_lookup()`` to get the ``GdkWindow*`` out of the X11 ``Window``, and then ``GDK_WINDOW_XDISPLAY()``.

Comment: @Tibo `wxGetDisplay()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just connect with `XOpenDisplay()`.  The Display structure is just the information for your connection to the X server.

`XGetInputFocus()` will give you the client window with focus on the X server to which you are connected.

Comment: That will be an extra connection.